# MySQL JDBC driver error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, database-connection

I keep getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)
at ttest.Sql.readFile(Sql.java:28)
at ttest.Sql.main(Sql.java:68)
```

to

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

on NetBeans and can't see why!

MySQL is running fine with JPA.

Do i need additional settings for JDBC?

burnt so much of my time!!

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need `MYSQL connector` in your class path to connect to MySql database from `JDBC`.
You ca get one from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).

Answer (score 1):

Copy **mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar** (it is in the C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector.J 5.1) into C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext

Answer (score 0):

MySQL connector is already present in Netbeans, you just have to import that into your project. Follow the given STeps

1. Click project properties
2. Click on libraries and then Add Library
3. Click on import ,then you will see many jars available
4. Select the Mysql JDBC driver and import it.

Thats it. Now try running your project.